# How to setup users and user groups on a distributed architecture?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, installation, authentication

I am learning ArcGIS distributed installation. I planned like this picture.

[image]

I read from installation documents about server users group.

1. agsAdmin
2. agsUsers

Which machine contains user groups and users? Web server, SOM or SOC PCs?
For example I installed Windows 2008 on  PC-1, 2, and 3 machines, all of these are default accounts. I installed PC-1 as SOM. PC-2 as SOC machine. Where my usergroups should be located or all pcs has these groups.

Comment: Which version of ArcGIS for Server are you using?  I'm guessing 10.0 but can you confirm?

Comment: Yes my version is 10.0. Is this important?

Comment: ["In ArcGIS 10.1 for Server, the SOM-SOC model has been replaced by the ArcGIS Server site."](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/install-guides/arcgis-server/10.1/index.html#//01nm0000000m000000)